# Formatting line breaks in a <textarea>

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea, styling

I am trying to PHP data that is posted from one place to another textarea.

Here is the case:
after doSearchTweet.php shows the tweets that are retrieved using twitter API, user can checked the tweets they want using a form.

The form will post the selected tweets a textarea input.

Here is the problem, I cannot style the selected tweets in the textarea.

For example: Username - Jakob Tweet - I need help in styling php!
I select this tweet and the data is post into the textarea, it shows this

> JakobI need help in styling php!

instead of

> Jakob
>
> I need help in styling php!

I tried using normal html tags like `<br/>` n/ in the textarea, instead of applying the html tags, it will appear as normal text like this

> Jakob< b r >I need help in styling php!

here is my code

```
<tr><td><label for="content"><span class="postBigFont">Content: </span></label></td>
<td colspan="4"><textarea cols="60" rows="15" name="content">
<?php
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $add = $_POST['add'];
        foreach ($add as $i){
        echo $user[$i];
        echo $content[$i];
    }?>
</textarea></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `"<br>"` with `"\n"` in your textarea output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $content);
```

Comment: Why do you put the variable in string literals? And this will not work if there are Unix-Newlines only ;)

Comment: Oh it shouldn't be like that... Sry

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `nl2br($text);` is the answer